# Setting Cookie in PHP Form Submit?

Tags: php, session

Here I have Situation to set the cookie after the form submitting into the same page.....

**Here is the Code:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$dbHandle = DBHandler::getInstance();
@session_start();
if($_POST['division'])
{
    $fromDiv =$_POST['division'];
    $divId =explode(',',$fromDiv);
    echo $divId[0].'~';
    echo $_COOKIE['preDiv'].'dfg'.'<br/>';
    setcookie("preDiv",$divId[0],time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    $_SESSION['division'] = $divId[0];
}
$sql=$dbHandle->execQuery("SELECT * FROM master_division");
$division_str = '<option value="">--select--</option>';
while($fetch = $dbHandle->fetchObjectQuery($sql))
{
    $division = $fetch->division_id.','.$fetch->name;
    $division_str .= '<option value="'.$division.'">'.$fetch->name.'</option>';
}

echo $_COOKIE['preDiv'].'dfg'.'<br/>';
echo $_SESSION['division'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="login" style="overflow: hidden;">

        <div class="login-box" style="position: absolute;z-index: 999;padding: 10px;width: 40%;min-height: 200px;margin-left:-20%;">
            <section class="portlet login-box-top" style="height:100%;">
                <header>
                    <h2 class="ac">CHOOSE DIVISION To MEDISMO CRM LOGIN</h2>
                </header>
                <section style="height:76%;">
                    <div id="popup_box" > <!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->
                    <div id="group_comp" style="margin-top:15%;margin-left:20%;">
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" style="border:none;">
                    <label><b>Choose Division:</b></label>
                    <select id="division" name="division"><?php echo $division_str;?></select>
                    <input type="submit" id="ok" value="OK" />
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyone suggest me what is wrong in it...

Comment: And the problem is? The cookie isn't set? It's being eaten? The cookie starts to talk with you? Or is the cookie on vacation? Maybe the cookie just has a paranoid fever and doesn't want to be bothered :|

Comment: i dont want the cookie to expire..............

Comment: Life isn't fair .. even cookies have to die at some point :| .. so the cookie isn't set, you said in a comment to an answer .. and how do you check it isn't set? What does `setcookie` return? .. `If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.`

Comment: then suggest me to expire it in one year..........ok dude.......

Comment: my problem is setcookie() itself it is not doing the work.......

Comment: to set the TTL of the cookie accordingly you can use my answer, I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved Guys.........

I just Submitted To another page and now it is coming fine.......

**Here is the code For Another Page**

```
<?php
@session_start();
if($_POST['division'])
{
    $fromDiv =$_POST['division'];
    $divId =explode(',',$fromDiv);
    setcookie("preDiv",$divId[0],time()+60*60*24*365);
    $_SESSION['division'] = $divId[0];
}
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To give the cookie a lifetime read through the following documentation

http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php

in here you find in the described paramterlist

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

the value `$expire` which you need to provide with a TTL, e.g. `time()+60*60*24*30` which would make the cookie valid for 30 days from now on!

If you want to have whatever you want to store available right away while outputting the html content, you should just put the $_COOKIE['whatever'] into a variable and use that

Comment: i tried with this but it is not giving any response dude....

Comment: so you are not seeing any `SET-COOKIE` headers on your response, once calling that script?

Comment: I am seeing you are calling `$_COOKIE` right after the `setcookie` call. That won't be possible. `$_COOKIE` will only inherit those values send by the client in the request headers.

Comment: @MatthiasLaug actually, it will be available on next page load ;)

Comment: exactly, where it is send to the script in the request headers :). It will never have the value just set by `setcookie` (if not the same value each call, of course)

Comment: but i want it in the same page itself dude.......

Comment: then let's be fancy and use plain variables :). Whatever you want to put into $_COOKIE put it into a variable and output it with the script. I think you are making it more complicated than it is

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set cookies that never expire, but..

If you don't want a cookie to expire, then you might want to set it for 20 years.

if you want your cookies to be available on current HTTP request (after you set them), you can do this trick:

```
function cookieSet(array $data){
   foreach($data as $key => $value){

      $_COOKIE[$key] = $value; // <- to make them available on current HTTP request

      setcookie($key, $value, time() + strtotime('+20 years'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoroding to [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), their is some limit about cookie for a website.
Are you sure you didn't hit the limit?

Comment: it is not meant by the limit the error is we can't set the cookie in the same page.............we have to set it in another page and then refer the cookie to here..........

Comment: haha.. nvm. it's good and the most important things is that u find the answer:)